# SQL C++/CLi - Way to know if something is in a table if yes use it's id, if not generate the new id and grab it

Tags: c++, sql, .net, sql-server

I have a DataBase with these links :
[MCD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHYBK.png)

I want to add new values in the Table 'Personnel'.
I made this query :

```
INSERT INTO Adresse (NoRue, Addresse, Ville, CP)
VALUES ('420','Rue des Lacs','Paris','75016');
DECLARE @Id1 AS int = @@identity;
INSERT INTO Date (Date)
VALUES (1999-02-21);
DECLARE @Id2 AS int = @@identity;
INSERT INTO Personnel (NomPersonnel, PrenomPersonnel, IdAdresse, IdDate)
VALUES ('Michel','Jean',@Id1, @Id2);
```

But it's creating a new date every time I will create new values. I want to know if I could check if a date already existing and if yes inserting the FK Personnel.IdDate. And if note creating a new Date and inserting the FK in Personnel.IdDate.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: FYI "`INSERT INTO Date (Date)
VALUES (1999-02-21);`" isn't going to do what you think. It's either going to error if you're using the newer date and time data type, or it'll insert the `datetime` `1905-05-31T00:00:00.000`: `1999-02-21 = 1976 = DATEADD(DAY,1976,'19000101') = 1905-05-31T00:00:00.000`.

Answer (score 0):

I made that :

```
int id_date = dataAccess->actionRowsID("SELECT * FROM Date WHERE Date IN ('" + getDate() + "')");
    if (id_date == 0 )
    {
        return "INSERT INTO Adresse (NoRue, Addresse, Ville, CP)" +
                    "VALUES('420', 'Rue des iddate0', 'City', '75016');" +
                    "DECLARE @Id1 AS int = @@identity;" +
                    "INSERT INTO Date(Date)" +
                    "VALUES('" + getDate() + "');" +
                    "DECLARE @Id2 AS int = @@identity;" +
                    "INSERT INTO Personnel(NomPersonnel, PrenomPersonnel, IdAdresse, IdDate)" +
                    "VALUES('" + getNom() + "', '" + getPrenom() + "', @Id1, @Id2);";
    }
    else
    {
        return "INSERT INTO Adresse (NoRue, Addresse, Ville, CP)" +
                    "VALUES('420', 'Rue des Iddatepas0', 'Stylax', '75016');" +
                    "DECLARE @Id1 AS int = @@identity;" +
                    "INSERT INTO Personnel(NomPersonnel, PrenomPersonnel, IdAdresse, IdDate)" +
                    "VALUES('" + getNom() + "', '" + getPrenom() + "', @Id1, "+ id_date + ");";
    }   
}
```

where actionRowsId is

```
int NS_Composants::CL_CAD::actionRowsID(String^ rqsql)
{
    int id;
    setSQL(rqsql);
    comm->CommandText = this->rq_sql;   //comm is SqlCommand object 
    conn->Open();                       //conn is the SqlConnection object
    id = Convert::ToInt32(comm->ExecuteScalar());
    conn->Close();
    return id;
}
```